# How to make swapable component in exJs or in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, extjs6

How to make swapable component in exJs or in javascript.

I have two components and both are dragabble.

```
            xtype : "panel",
            title: 'My Apps',
            region: 'east',
            width: 290,
            items:[{
                xtype : 'panel',
                cls: 'myCLS',
                iconCls : 'app-info-appstore',
                title: 'Home',
                draggable : true,
                html : 'Home.',
                listeners: {
                    'render': function(panel) {
                        panel.body.on('click', function() {
                            alert('onclick');
                        });
                     }
                 }
                
            },{
                xtype : 'panel',
                cls: 'myCLS',
                title: 'Profile',
                iconCls : "app-info-iconToure",
                draggable : true,
                html : 'Apps',
            }
```

When I drag one to another  it is overlapping. How can we swap the positon of both element in extJS.

Any other library help will also work.

Answer (score 1):

onDrop you add it to a the parent container via [insert](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/modern/Ext.Container.html#method-insert).

To get the correct position you can either calculate it based on the mouse position or ...

onDrop you get the target dom element you are currently at.

```
const extComponent = Ext.ComponentManager.from(domEl),
      currentIndex = ... // search for the position of that item in parent

parent.insert(droppedItem, currentIndex);
```

**Further work**

- If you use a placeholder proxy you can even preview these.
- Use snap if your components are the same size.

**Example**

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3h14)

Comment: @Dinkheler I have rewarded bounty to you.

Comment: @Dinkheler Thank u for the fiddle. Let me check the fiddle and impletement it.

Comment: @Dinkheler  +1 your fiddle is working fine but it is not consitent. Though I am workin on the changes and update once i get some sucess.